Boolean clause count in Apache solr query
Note: Solr version used here is 8.11.1.
I am exploring the max Boolean query functionality area of SOLR apache and bit confused on how the number of boolean clasues being calculated in a query. Below are 3 examples of queries and the number of boolean queries it has calculating.
"Too many clauses in boolean query: encountered=3 configured in solrconfig.xml via maxBooleanClauses=1",
SolrQuery=rows=250&start=0&q=:&fq=((siteid:505)+OR+(metaData:userID*)+OR+(metaData:microBlogID*))+AND+(application:application_ms)&sort=score+desc&fl=id,application,metaData,siteid,docType_t,tag,contentAuthorName_t,contentAuthorID_i,folderID_i&defType=edismax&qt=/select
"Too many clauses in boolean query: encountered=2 configured in solrconfig.xml via maxBooleanClauses=1"
SolrQuery=rows=250&start=0&q=:&fq=((siteid:505+OR+siteid:504)+OR+(metaData:userID*)+OR+(metaData:microBlogID*))+AND+(application:application_ms)&sort=score+desc&fl=id,application,metaData,siteid,docType_t,tag,contentAuthorName_t,contentAuthorID_i,folderID_i&defType=edismax&qt=/select
"Too many clauses in boolean query: encountered=3 configured in solrconfig.xml via maxBooleanClauses=1"
SolrQuery=rows=250&start=0&q=:&fq=((siteid:505+OR+siteid:504+OR+siteid:503)+OR+(metaData:userID*)+OR+(metaData:microBlogID*))+AND+(application:application_ms)&sort=score+desc&fl=id,application,metaData,siteid,docType_t,tag,contentAuthorName_t,contentAuthorID_i,folderID_i&defType=edismax&qt=/select
Can anybody explain how the number of clauses is being calculated here?

In Solr 8, I recall this is the number of clauses in enforced for each BooleanQuery (direct descendants within parenthesis).  With nesting, you can subvert this limit.  In Solr 9, it is the total clauses no matter how it's nested.
In practice, I find this limit to be more painful than it is helpful.  It tries to protect Solr performance at the expense of preventing users from running their queries, which is the point of search!  I suggest that you set the limit very high, maybe a thousand.
